# File ID in Azure Blob Storage [AZURE-BLOB]

Tags: azure, rest, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is there any field such as fileID in Azure Blob Storage like modified_time, creation_time? which can be used to uniquely identify a file apart from its name.
There is no such thing mentioned in the link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get `modified_time` `creation_time` from this rest API： [get blob property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-properties) in response header with key: `Last-Modified` and `x-ms-creation-time`:

[image]

There is no fileID for Azure storage blob as an identifier, as @GauravMantri mentioned, Azure uses a blob’s URL as its unique identifier.

If a fileID is necessary for you, you can set it as [metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/organize-blobs-properties-metadata/2-manage-blob-data-using-properties-and-metadata) by [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-metadata), and filter blobs by the metadata property you have set.

Comment: I would not recommend using metadata to store id as metadata is user defined (a user can assign same id to multiple blobs) and is editable (a user may change the value or even delete the metadata).

Comment: @GauravMantri It is a workaround if this value is necessary for some scenarios. And yes, users need to maintain this value by themselves.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can use a blob’s URL as its unique identifier.

Comment: Yes but I need something like a FileID. GoogleDrive provides a unique fileID something like that, So just to confirm there is no such thing as FileID here in Azure right?

Comment: AFAIK, that’s correct. No system property of a blob like file id.